# How to configure xfce4 search box?

Tags: xfce

Currently, the `xfce4-search-box` only searches for applications. Is there any way to configure it so that it searches for `files`, `directories`, and finally if nothing matches, the `web`? Also, typing a `url` in the search should open the `url` in the `default` browser.

The search box:

[image: xfce4-search-box]

Comment: Your question is specific to xfce so it's better to ask here https://forum.xfce.org/index.php